# Avoiding global variables making boost asio socket wrapper

Tags: c++, boost, asio

i have this `socket-tcp.h` with an wrapper of socket implementation using boost asio:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

static const std::string PORT = "65432";  
static const std::string HOST = "127.0.0.1";  

struct Client
{
    boost::asio::io_service& io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
    
    Client(boost::asio::io_service& svc, std::string const& host, std::string const& port) 
        : io_service(svc), socket(io_service) 
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint = resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query(host, port));
        boost::asio::connect(this->socket, endpoint);
    };

    void send(std::string const& message) {
        socket.send(boost::asio::buffer(message));
    }
};


boost::asio::io_service svc;
Client client(svc, HOST, PORT);

class TcpSocket
{

    private:
        std::string HOST; 
        std::string PORT;
        
    public:
        
        TcpSocket (std::string const& host, std::string const& port): HOST{ host },PORT{ port }
        {
        }

        void send(std::string const& message)
        {
            boost::thread t(client_thread,boost::ref(message),boost::ref(HOST),boost::ref(PORT));
            t.join();
        }

        static void client_thread(std::string const& message,std::string const& host,std::string const& port) 
        {
            client.send(message); 
        }
            
};
```

so that my main file looks like:

```
#include "socket-tcp.h"

int main()
{
    TcpSocket socket(PORT,HOST);
    std::string message = "socket implemented using global variables";
    while (true)
    {
        socket.send(message);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a way of implement this without the global variables

```
boost::asio::io_service svc;
Client client(svc, HOST, PORT);
```

such that `TcpSocket`  be like:

```
class TcpSocket
{

    //Object* myObject; // Will not try to call the constructor or do any initializing
    //myObject = new Object(...);  // Initialised now
    private:
        std::string HOST; 
        std::string PORT;
        boost::asio::io_service svc;
        
    public:
        
        TcpSocket (std::string const& host, std::string const& port): HOST{ host },PORT{ port }
        {
            Client client(svc, HOST, PORT);
        }

        void send(std::string const& message)
        {
            boost::thread t(client_thread,boost::ref(message),boost::ref(HOST),boost::ref(PORT));
            t.join();
        }

        static void client_thread(std::string const& message,std::string const& host,std::string const& port) 
        {
            client.send(message); 
        }
            
};
```

but i end up with the runtime error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  resolve: Service not found
```

is there a way to avoid using these global variables (objects), and keeping the same socket open all the time, without closing and opening it again at each new message?

I accept better implementations or suggestions for this wrapper, but the goal is to keep main as simple and clear as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "service not found" merely means that the port is not a valid service. That's because you swapped host and port parameters.

But that is the least of your worries.

---

You're playing fast and loose with object lifetimes. For example, you pass `message` all the way to another thread &&by reference** (`std::string const&`), but the object referenced lives on the stack (as a function argument) so that invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Besides, it's not clear how the thread (or `client_thread`) is supposed to access the `Client` instance (that your code constructs as a local variable in the `TcpSocket` constructor only). Let alone that it would be unsafe to share that client across threads.

### Medium Fix

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/243b8488e3d793ec)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

static const std::string HOST = "127.0.0.1";  
static const std::string PORT = "65432";  

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

struct Client
{
    tcp::socket socket;

    //template <typename Executor>
    using Executor = boost::asio::io_service&;
    Client(Executor executor, std::string const& host, std::string const& port)
        : socket(executor)
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted(host) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::quoted(port) << std::endl;
        auto ep = tcp::resolver{socket.get_executor()}.resolve(host, port);
        connect(socket, ep);
    };

    void send(std::string const& message) {
        socket.send(boost::asio::buffer(message));
    }
};

class TcpSocket {
  private:
    std::string             _host;
    std::string             _port;
    boost::asio::io_service _svc;

  public:
    TcpSocket(std::string const& host, std::string const& port)
        : _host{host}
        , _port{port}
    {
    }

    void send(std::string const& message)
    {
        boost::thread t( //
            client_thread, boost::ref(_svc), message, _host, _port);
        t.join();
    }

    static void client_thread( //
        boost::asio::io_service& svc,
        std::string              message, // NOT A REFERENCE
        std::string              host,    // same
        std::string              port)
    {
        Client client(svc, host, port);
        client.send(message);
    }
};

//#include "socket-tcp.h"

int main()
{
    TcpSocket   socket(HOST, PORT);
    std::string const message = "socket implemented using global variables";
    while (true) {
        socket.send(message);
    }
}
```

### More Notes

The thread is by definition useless, since you join it immediately. But if you really wanted that, please consider c++11 style:

```
void send(std::string const& message)
{
    boost::thread t([=, &_svc] {
        Client client(_svc, _host, _port);
        client.send(message);
    });
    t.join();
}
```

It makes far more sense to do it on the main thread:

```
void send(std::string const& message)
{
    Client client(_svc, _host, _port);
    client.send(message);
}
```

Or to use async IO. Note that you should probably prefer to pass executors rather than sharing references to an execution context. Also, prefer `io_context` because `io_service` is deprecated.

Here's a simplified program that still does the same:  **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3761db2a5c9476e4)**

### BONUS - Async With A Thread Pool

Seems like  you wanted the messages to be delivered in async fashion. However, you didn't know how to get threads in the background. Regardless, it wouldn't be a safe idea to "just create a new thread" each time. The professional approach is to use a thread pool.

This example uses a ddefault `boost::asio::thread_pool` and throws in a strand (even though it's not currently required) and a Session object to hold all the state for a single message. Note that we now cache the resolver results. That can be a good thing ,or a bad thing depending on your application.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2eaf3a86bfe58a22)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

class TcpClient {
  public:
    TcpClient(std::string const& host, std::string const& port)
        : _ep(tcp::resolver{_io}.resolve(host, port))
    { }

    void send(std::string message)
    {
        boost::make_shared<Session>( //
            make_strand(_io.get_executor()), std::move(message), _ep)
            ->run();
    }

    ~TcpClient() {
        //_io.stop(); // optionally
        _io.join();
    }

  private:
    boost::asio::thread_pool _io;
    tcp::resolver::results_type _ep ;

    struct Session : boost::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
        Session(auto executor, std::string message,
                tcp::resolver::results_type ep)
            : _socket(executor)
            , _message(std::move(message))
            , _ep(ep)
        {
        }

        void run() {
            async_connect( //
                _socket, _ep,
                [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec,
                                                  tcp::endpoint) {
                    async_write(_socket, boost::asio::buffer(_message),
                                [this, self](error_code ec, size_t) {});
                });
        }

        tcp::socket                 _socket;
        std::string                 _message;
        tcp::resolver::results_type _ep;
    };
};

//#include "socket-tcp.h"

int main()
{
    TcpClient socket("127.0.0.1", "65432");
    for (int i = 0; i<100; ++i) {
        socket.send("socket implemented using async IO on thread pool " +
                    std::to_string(i) + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Added a version with a threadpool for good measure http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/